# Highlight current section using alert in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

The following

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}
```

inserts the table of contents at the beginning of each section, such that the current section is rendered normally and the others are shaded. I would like to have a similar effect but instead of shading the other sections, I'd like to `alert` the current one. Since, according to the manual, the allowed styles are `show`, `shaded`, and `hide`, I don't know how to accomplish this. Is there a canonical way to obtain this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `section in toc` and `section in toc shaded` colors appropriately:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=alerted text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{fg=structure}
\begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section{Test section four}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If "other" sections should not be shaded, you can add

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=alerted text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{bg=structure!20,fg=structure}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc shaded}[default][100]
\begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section{Test section four}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, however, now if I have somewhere `\tableofcontents` (without any option), then all entries are alerted. Is there a way out of the loop?

Comment: @Dror sure; please see my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Why did you define the colors and templates in the `\AtBeginSection` command and not outside of this command? I think it won't be overridden outside this scope, or does it?